# ASP.NET 5 using openidconnect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

1. I'm confused which package to use:

   - Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect "1.0.0-beta4"
   - Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect "1.0.0-beta3"
2. How to redirect to the external provider?
   I've added `[Authorize]` to the controller action and  `app.UseCookieAuthentication();app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication();` to `Startup.cs`.When I hit the controller action marked with `[Authorized]` attribute error 401 occurs but no redirection.
   To redirect I need to manually redirect with
   `Response.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`
   So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you meant ASP.NET MVC 5 or ASP.NET 5 and working on VS2015?

Comment: VS2015RC
ASP.NET5
MVC6

Comment: I have the second problem. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They renamed `Microsoft.AspNet.Security` to `Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication`, so you should use `Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect "1.0.0-beta4"`.
2. use this config in `Startup.cs`

   ```
   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.ClientId = "CientId";
       options.Authority = "https://yourIdentityProviderUrl";
       options.RedirectUri = "http://localhost:49181";
       options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
       options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
       options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
       options.Scope = "openid profile roles read write ";
   });
   ```

Comment: Now also available in [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) (for anyone heading down the same rabbit hole as me)